# PHP UNIQUE user movie rating

Tags: php, mysql, unique-key

On my site when a user is logged in, they can give a 1-5 rating on a movie.

What I want to do is make it so that database knows which user gave the rating and to update there rating if they click it again rather than creating a new entry, so each user can not have more than one rating per movie.

Tables:

login - id, user, password

movies - id, movie_name, movie_year

user_movie_ratings - id, user_id, movie_id, rating

At the moment when you login, you're taken to a members page the session is checked to ensure you're logged in, and then the list of all the movies is displayed and then when you click the move name you get take to a rating page where you can give it a rating of 1-5, then you are taken back to the movie page and the avg total rating is displayed beside the move name.

The user can just keep doing this over and incorrectly changing the avg rating.

I think I know what I have to do I just dont know how to do it:

Get session user name compare to database user name

Get the id linked to that user name

Post that id with the rating

Use UNIQUE KEY and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in some way to insure that they can only post once else it gets updated

movie.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

<?php
require_once 'sessionCheck.php';
require_once 'init.php';

$movie = null;

if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

    $movie = $con->query
    ("
        SELECT movies.id, movies.movie_name, AVG(user_movie_ratings.rating) AS rating
        FROM movies
        LEFT JOIN user_movie_ratings
        ON movies.id = user_movie_ratings.movie_id
        WHERE movies.id = {$id}
    ")->fetch_object();

}

?>


<head>
<title>Movies</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">   

        <div id="login">
            <?php include 'loginCheck.php';?>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="content"> 



    <?php if ($movie): ?>

    <div class="movie">

         Movie Name: <?php echo $movie->movie_name; ?>.

        <div class="movie_rating">
            Rating: <?php echo round($movie->rating); ?>/5
        </div>

        <div class="movie-rate">
            Rate this movie:
            <?php foreach(range(1, 5) as $rating): ?>
            <a href="rate.php?movie=<?php echo $movie->id; ?>&rating=<?php echo $rating; ?>"><?php echo $rating; ?></a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
 <div id="footer"> This is the Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

rate.php

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

if(isset($_GET['movie'], $_GET['rating'])) {

$movie = (int)$_GET['movie'];
$rating = (int)$_GET['rating'];

if(in_array($rating, array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))) {

$exists = $con->query("SELECT id FROM movies WHERE id = {$movie}")->num_rows ? true : false;

if ($exists) {
$con->query("INSERT INTO user_movie_ratings (movie_id, rating) VALUES ({$movie}, {$rating} )");
}
}
header('Location: movie.php?id=' . $movie);
}
```

login

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="reg.php">Register</a></p>
<form action="" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) 
        {
            $user=$_POST['user'];
            $pass=$_POST['pass'];

            require_once 'init.php';

            $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
            $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($numrows!=0)
                {
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    $dbusername=$row['username'];
                    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
                }

                if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
                {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

                    /* Redirect browser */
                    header("Location: member.php");
                }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "Invalid username or password!";
                }

                }
                else 
                {
                    echo "All fields are required!";
                }
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what exactly are You asking for?

Comment: I am asking how I would get the users id based on the username being the same as the session username and then post that along side the movie_id and the rating so as the user can only rate the movie once

Comment: Why would you store username to the session and then use that to find user's ID? Why don't you store user's ID as well after they log on? Then all you need to do is add `user_id` column to `user_movie_ratings` and create a unique key out of `user_id, movie_id` and voila - no users can rate one movie more than once. Keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll list the steps you need to undertake in order to achieve what you want.

- Store the USER_ID to the session along with their username (or any other data). Do not store username and then query every time to obtain their ID. That makes no sense
- Add a unique key `(user_id, movie_id)` and this is the fun step - do not perform any kind of checks, just insert the data. If the user has voted for the movie, the key will be there and the insert will fail. In PHP this will be interpreted as an exception and that's what you want
- Catch the exception in case of failure and notify the user they have already voted.
- Use prepared statements to avoid any potential SQL injections and to speed things up (MySQL plays nicely with performance and prepared statements)

Overall, you can reduce your logic and your code if you follow these steps.

Comment: Thank you very much I have added the login code I am using above (quite new to php sorry if it was a silly question)

Comment: It's not a silly question, especially if you are new to PHP / SQL. Just remember, keep things simple and have fun coding :)

Comment: i seem to be getting stuck I am doing `$dbuserid=$row['id'];` then `$_SESSION['sess_userid']=$dbuserid;` but when i try to echo that out one the movies page i get  `Undefined index: sess_userid`

Comment: Hey N.B. sorry to bother you, but do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can't really tell what's wrong, there's too much info missing there. Try to check which rows you get back after user logs in (var_dump) and try to check what keys are in your session and debug from there.

Comment: OK i am getting there I got the user id being posted to the database, all I need to do now is make it unique and then update there rating if they click it again. Do i just set th fileds in the database to unique or do i do somehting else

Comment: You create a unique index out of both keys (user_id and movie_id). If you need to update the vote of the user for a particular movie, research MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax. Technically, you can do this voting in a single query. Also, make sure you inform yourself about PDO or mysqli since `mysql_` functions are obsolete (and direct querying without escaping user input is insecure).

Comment: Thanks I got it working you were very helpful, on to the next bit, picking movies out of the list based on there rating.